# Was Cicero the Adoring Fan?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

In TES Oblivion, after becoming the Grand Champion of the [Arena](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_City,_Arena_District), you meet an [Adoring Fan](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoring_Fan).

In TES Skyrim, inside of [Cicero's Journal Volume 1](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cicero's_Journal_-_Volume_1), you find that he posed as a fan of the Arena in the Imperial City.

In fact, at the bottom of the Adoring Fan page in the Trivia section, it says exactly what I said about the journal, but no reference to how he did it, who he was assassinating or when it was.

TES Oblivion takes place at the end of the Third Era (which lasted for 433 years), whereas TES Skyrim is based 201 years into the Fourth Era.

Was Cicero *really* there? How did he survive 200+ years?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the trivia reference you are referring to is [debated](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion_talk:Adoring_Fan#The_Adoring_Fan_reference_in_Cicero.27s_journal).

Comment: @JoshPetrie I see no debate there. The only debate I see is about whether it belongs on the wiki and, if so, on which page.

Comment: @Studoku Yea, that's what I mean (the reference to the trivia section that Finn is making is not potentially confusing since there was debate on the wiki as to where that content belonged, and the Trivia section is currently missing from the page he links). "Debated" was a poor word choice in hindsight.

Comment: Well after reading that "Debated" Wiki page, I understand the fact that he wasn't there perfectly now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He wasn't.

The passage in Cicero's journal is probably a reference to the adoring fan from Oblivion but it does not mean Cicero was that adoring fan. There have been many arena champions over the years aside from the Hero of Kvatch and many would have attracted fans.

Cicero's Journal also includes the dates of his assassinations. His journal states he completed the arena contract in 4E 187- only 14 years before the events of Skyrim. It is theoretically possible the Hero of Kvatch survived and was somehow still the arena champion (if s/he was an elf or a vampire for example) but this is a moot point- Cicero was not The Adoring Fan.

It's also worth noting that the adoring fan in Oblivion looks completely different, sounds completely different, acts completely different and is a **completely different race** from Cicero.

Comment: Yes, but in his journal it said he was "Disguised" as one. Possibly could've used his skills to somehow dress up as a completely different race.

Comment: @FinnRayment Cicero's journal includes the dates (with years) and the assassination occurred 187 years after the Oblivion Crisis.

Comment: It should also be noted that various Mer individuals have lived to be some several thousand years of age, albeit usually through liberal use of magic. To further what Studoku has already mentioned, the Adoring Fan in Oblivion is a Bosmer, whereas Cicero in Skyrim is an Imperial. That would have to be some pretty funky magic to make that one happen!

Comment: Haha. Yes. I understand @Studoku.

Answer (score 3):

Some speculate so, yes. And via thorough research it is easy to understand why. Cicero, being a master of disguise, could have potentially fooled the Hero into believing he was a Bosmer child. However, there are some deductions:

Cicero is mad, so I believe if you were to turn down the Adoring Fan, he wouldn't be so patient.

Also, you can potentially just brutally murder the Fan, which means he wouldn't even be alive in the next game.

Last and most importantly, Bosmer, Altmer, Orsimer, Dunmer, Falmer, etc. live much longer than Men. They are not immortal, but live for quite a while. So the Adoring Fan could be alive by the events of Skyrim, but Cicero couldn't be. If I am correct, our beloved Cicero, correct me if I'm wrong, is an Imperial. Which again, correct me if I'm not right, don't live as long. In order for Cicero to be alive during the Oblivion Crisis, he would have to be over two hundred years old by the events of Skyrim. Imperials, being Men, don't live that long.

So, it's a good theory, but it's just implausible. But I could be wrong.

Unless, of course, Cicero is just another alias for something greater...

Answer (score -2):

Cicero could have killed the adoring fan and merge his personality with himself, just like he did with the jester. Its Cicero's way of honoring people he has killed.